# Mudblazor pie/doughnut slice colors

Tags: charts, blazor, mudblazor

I am exploring Mudblazor. I created a doughnut chart and it works fine. But I need to define the colors of the slices of the pie/doughnut. I see you can have a class for the entire chart, but how do set custom colors for each slice of the pie?

The default for a 3 slice pie is like blue, teal and gold. I need to change those colors and will need to be changed in code also.

The theming palette options don't seem to have options for this.

Thanks,

Michael

Edit: I figured it out. In case anyone else needs to do this. Example:

```
ChartOptions options = new ChartOptions();

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    string[] colors = { "#ff0000", "#00FF00","#0000ff" };
    options.ChartPalette = colors;
}
```

Chart-add ChartOptions="@options":

Comment: OK, I figured it out. In case anyone else needs to do this:

Comment: Well done! Please add the solution as answer and accept it. [SO explicitly encourages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow) to do that. An answer hidden in the question is hard to find for others.

Comment: @michaeld note that you can do that in one go: `ChartOptions options = new() { ChartPalette = new[] { "#ff0000", "#00FF00", "#0000ff" } };`

Comment: This was my first post on StackOverflow. I apologize, but I don't know what you mean by "Please add the solution as answer and accept it." How do you do that?

Comment: @michaeld Scroll down and put the answer in the text box labeled "Your Answer", then click the "Post Your Answer" button.